# How to create a makefile to use the mpir and mpfr libraries

Tags: c, visual-c++, makefile, static-libraries, mpfr

I've recently written a C program which uses the public-domain mpir and mpfr libraries.  I've been compiling it on Windows, using the Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 compiler.  To get that to work, I had to do the following:

- Download / build the mpir and mpfr libraries from http://gladman.plushost.co.uk/oldsite/computing/gmp4win.php
- Move the files `mpir.h` and `mpfr.h` into the Include directory for the Microsoft compiler
- Move the files `mpir.lib`, `mpir.pdb`, `mpfr.lib` and `mpfr.pdb` into the lib directory for the Microsoft compiler
- `#include` `mpir.h` and `mpfr.h` in the program
- Compile using `cl <..module names..> /link mpir.lib mpfr.lib`

I now want to send the source / header files I've written to someone else, along with a makefile that they can use to compile the code and check that it works.  Since that person won't have the mpir / mpfr libraries installed, and might not be using the same compiler, I'm not quite sure how to do this.

Here is what I can do:

- Send them the binaries `mpir.lib`, `mpir.pdb`, `mpfr.lib` and `mpfr.pdb` as well as the source / header files.

Here is what I can't do:

- Send them my entire Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 setup
- Ask them to stick files in their `Include` and `lib` directories (unless there's no other way)

Ideally, I should be able to send them the source/header files, together with the pertinent mpir/mpfr binaries, and a makefile which they can then run to build the program.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why on earth are you adding those files to your compiler installation path?? The compiler has [command line options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610ecb4h.aspx) for specifying search paths.

For instance,

```
cl /I"path/to/mpfr/header" <...filenames...> /link /LIBPATH:"path/to/mpfr/lib" mpir.lib mpfr.lib
```

You should only have to send your source code, *mpir.h*, *mpir.lib*, *mpfr.h* and *mpfr.lib*. The PDB files contain debugging information, and are not necessary for compilation.

Also, I don't know how to create a makefile, but a simple batch file with the command above should suffice for something so simple.

Comment: Thanks very much - that was a huge help, and I know exactly what to do now.